# Как получить число типа float из двух байт?

Tags: c#

Как получить число типа float из двух байт?
Есть два байта. Допустим 0x02 - младшая часть  и 0x04 - старшая часть.
Как мне получить число типа float?

Comment: Чему должно быть равно полученное число?

Comment: байты должны быть приведены тем или иным образом в массив байт. Далее при помощи BitConvert.ToInt16(byte[],0) производится чтение, где "byte[]" источник, для конвертации, а "0" - стартовое положение курсора в обозначенном массиве.

Comment: @Garrus_En Так автору же не int требуется, а float.

Comment: Длина типа float - четыре байта, а не два. Что-то вы не договариваете.

Comment: Согласен с предыдущим ответом, почитайте спецификацию на float https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8. Тут возможно два байта всегда равны нулю, тогда можно использовать неуправляемый код

Answer (score 1):

Предположим, ваше число представлено вот так:

```
float f = 2.7f;
// Приводим float к массиву байт
byte[] arr = BitConverter.GetBytes(f);
// И обратный процесс
float i = BitConverter.ToSingle(arr,0);
```

Надеюсь, поможет понять.

Comment: float i = BitConvert.ToSingle(arr,0);

Comment: поправлю в ответе, спасибо. Хотя Int16 по размеру те же 2 байта

Comment: только хранятся они в памяти по другому...

Comment: А как ПРАВИЛЬНО преобразовать? Важен порядок сам при преобразовании?

Comment: не понятен комментарий, что вы имеете в виду? что значит Правильно преобразовать? Я привёл пример преобразования из float в byte и обратно.

Comment: Тут вполне корректное преобразование, хотя можно выполнить тоже самое, но используя небезопасный код

Comment: @Alexsandr Ter А в чем разница между безопасным и небезопасным кодом?

Comment: Безопасный код  в C# это код генерируемый компилятором при этом осуществляются его проверка и верификация. Небезопасный код не проверяется и в нем возможна работа напрямую с адресами и манипулировать байтами.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms228628(v=vs.90).aspx